# hdfs distcp failing to copy from hdfs to s3

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs, distcp, aws-snowball

We have a snowball configured in our inhouse staging node with end-point `http://10.91.16.213:8080`. It all works properly, I can even list files in this snowball via s3 cli command

```
aws s3 ls my-bucket/data/ --endpoint-url=http://10.91.16.213:8080`
```

Now I am trying to use the hadoop distcp command to copy data from hdfs to s3 snowball. first I tested hadoop distcp command to copy some files to actual s3 test-bucket in my aws account,

```
hadoop distcp \
-Dfs.s3a.fast.upload=true \
-Dfs.s3a.access.key=AKIAUPWDYDZTSGWUWJWN \
-Dfs.s3a.secret.key=<my-secret> \ 
hdfs://path/to/data/ \
s3a://test-bucket-anum/
```

The above command executes fine and starts the copying job in hadoop cluster. Now in order to copy to my in-house snowballs, all I have to do is change the endpoint. This is what I try;

```
hadoop distcp \
-Dfs.s3a.endpoint=http://10.91.16.213:8080 \
-Dfs.s3a.fast.upload=true \
-Dfs.s3a.access.key=AKIACEMGMYDQNJXGQ2DEOBXG42SQCFR2ZJFTDED3HX3KLVTLOIN6AH3FSDHUF \
-Dfs.s3a.secret.key=<snowball-secret>  \ 
hdfs://path/to/data/ \
s3a://my-bucket/
```

The above command fails with following error;

```
20/09/02 19:20:22 INFO s3a.S3AFileSystem: Caught an AmazonClientException, which means the client encountered a serious internal problem while trying to communicate with S3, such as not being able to access the network.
20/09/02 19:20:22 INFO s3a.S3AFileSystem: Error Message: {}com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to unmarshall response (Failed to parse XML document with handler class com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler). Response Code: 200, Response Text: OK
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to unmarshall response (Failed to parse XML document with handler class com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler). Response Code: 200, Response Text: OK
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:738)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:399)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3480)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.setTargetPathExists(DistCp.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.main(DistCp.java:430)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Failed to parse XML document with handler class com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseXmlInputStream(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:150)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseListBucketObjectsResponse(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:279)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$ListObjectsUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unmarshallers.java:75)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$ListObjectsUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unmarshallers.java:72)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(S3XmlResponseHandler.java:62)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(S3XmlResponseHandler.java:31)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:712)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid value for IsTruncated field: 
true
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler.endElement(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:647)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseXmlInputStream(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:141)
    ... 18 more
20/09/02 19:20:22 ERROR tools.DistCp: Invalid arguments: 
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to unmarshall response (Failed to parse XML document with handler class com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler). Response Code: 200, Response Text: OK
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:738)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:399)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3480)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.setTargetPathExists(DistCp.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.main(DistCp.java:430)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Failed to parse XML document with handler class com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseXmlInputStream(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:150)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseListBucketObjectsResponse(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:279)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$ListObjectsUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unmarshallers.java:75)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$ListObjectsUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unmarshallers.java:72)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(S3XmlResponseHandler.java:62)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(S3XmlResponseHandler.java:31)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:712)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid value for IsTruncated field: 
true
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler.endElement(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:647)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseXmlInputStream(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:141)
    ... 18 more
Invalid arguments: Unable to unmarshall response (Failed to parse XML document with handler class com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler). Response Code: 200, Response Text: OK
usage: distcp OPTIONS [source_path...] <target_path>
              OPTIONS
 -append                Reuse existing data in target files and append new
                        data to them if possible
 -async                 Should distcp execution be blocking
 -atomic                Commit all changes or none
 -bandwidth <arg>       Specify bandwidth per map in MB
 -delete                Delete from target, files missing in source
 -diff <arg>            Use snapshot diff report to identify the
                        difference between source and target
 -f <arg>               List of files that need to be copied
 -filelimit <arg>       (Deprecated!) Limit number of files copied to <= n
 -i                     Ignore failures during copy
 -log <arg>             Folder on DFS where distcp execution logs are
                        saved
 -m <arg>               Max number of concurrent maps to use for copy
 -mapredSslConf <arg>   Configuration for ssl config file, to use with
                        hftps://
 -overwrite             Choose to overwrite target files unconditionally,
                        even if they exist.
 -p <arg>               preserve status (rbugpcaxt)(replication,
                        block-size, user, group, permission,
                        checksum-type, ACL, XATTR, timestamps). If -p is
                        specified with no <arg>, then preserves
                        replication, block size, user, group, permission,
                        checksum type and timestamps. raw.* xattrs are
                        preserved when both the source and destination
                        paths are in the /.reserved/raw hierarchy (HDFS
                        only). raw.* xattrpreservation is independent of
                        the -p flag. Refer to the DistCp documentation for
                        more details.
 -sizelimit <arg>       (Deprecated!) Limit number of files copied to <= n
                        bytes
 -skipcrccheck          Whether to skip CRC checks between source and
                        target paths.
 -strategy <arg>        Copy strategy to use. Default is dividing work
                        based on file sizes
 -tmp <arg>             Intermediate work path to be used for atomic
                        commit
 -update                Update target, copying only missingfiles or
                        directories
```

Here are some other hadoop configurations I tried aswell, with no luck.

`-Dfs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled=false` : since my endpoint is http.

`-Dfs.s3a.region=eu-west-1`

Am I missing something ?

**UPDATE:**

As the error message also includes `Invalid arguments:`  I suppose I might be providing some invalid chars into the args, so I tried writing these options in `/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml` as follows;

```
<property>
 <name>fs.s3a.endpoint</name>
 <value>http://10.91.16.213:8080</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>fs.s3a.fast.upload</name>
 <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
 <value>AKIACEMGMYDQNJXGQ2DEOBXG42SQCFR2ZJFTDED3HX3KLVTLOIN6AH3FSDHUF</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
 <value><snowball-secret></value>
</property>
```

but got same error message :(

**UPDATE 2:**

After reading [this](http://www.deplication.net/2015/01/aws-tip-of-day-working-around-s3-failed.html), it looks like s3 xml parsing problem while doing ListObjects. AWS client has this option `.withEncodingType("url");`, but couldn't find anything similar for hadoop distcp.

Answer (score 0):

the s3a connector does not support working with an S3 snowball device -and will not do so unless and until someone sits down to implement all of [HADOOP-14710](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-14710).

nobody is doing that as of february 2022. if you or anyone else reading this page want the feature

1. check the JIRA to see if it is done, if it is, use a version of hadoop with the feature.
2. if it's not fixed at all -this is your chance to contribute to the community